# How to get ALL kinds of reverse package dependencies: reverse-depends pendant for non-Ubuntu distributions

Tags: debian, package-management, rpm, dependencies, deb

I would like to find *all* possible reverse dependencies (no need for recursive reverse dependencies) of a certain package `p`, that is, I want to find all packages which depend on `p`. This shall include reverse dependencies on `p`'s source package and also reverse *build* dependencies.

If I understand it correctly, there are 4 types of reverse dependencies:

1. `r` depends on `p`
2. `r` depends on source package of `p`
3. Building `r` requires `p`
4. Building `r` requires the source package of `p`

I would like to find all of them.

For Debian, there is `apt-rdepends -r` but the [manual](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/aptrdependsmanpage.htm) says:

```
 apt-rdepends cannot do reverse build-dependencies.
```

For Ubuntu, there is `reverse-depends`, which seems to let me do what I want but it seems to be Ubuntu specific, as the manual pages states it is

> Provided by: ubuntu-dev-tools_0.153_all

Are there reverse-depends-like tools which will work for non-Ubuntu distributions, especially those using `deb` and `rpm` packages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Debian and derivatives there are six types of dependencies:

- pre-depends
- depends
- recommends
- suggests
- build-depends
- build-depends-indep

Each of these give corresponding reverse dependencies. To list them you can use `grep-dctrl`:

```
grep-dctrl -FBuild-Depends mypackage -w -sPackage /var/lib/apt/lists/*Sources
```

will list all the packages which build-depend on `mypackage`, *i.e.* `mypackage`'s non-recursive reverse build-dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, despite the name, it's also available on Debian: https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/ubuntu-dev-tools