# How to find which package required another package?

Tags: dpkg, dependencies

I am looking for which no-longer-installed package depended on rsync. An `apt-get autoremove` now wants to remove `rsync` so I'm guessing that it was installed as part of a dependency rather than manually, and I'm curious which package depended on it.

Can I search back in logs for something like *"X requires Y, so I will install Y as well"*? Or does it even store which reverse dependency required it, just like it stores that it was not installed by the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt` doesn’t remember which reverse dependency caused it to install `rsync`, but it does log all its actions in `/var/log/apt`, so you might find the dependency there:

```
zgrep rsync /var/log/apt/history.log*
```

Look for a line saying that `rsync` was installed automatically; one of the non-automatic packages there should be the source of the installation.

You can also examine `rsync`’s reverse dependencies, *e.g.* using `aptitude`, or `apt-rdepends -r`, or `reverse-depends` (in `ubuntu-dev-tools`), or [`grep-dctrl`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/214161/86440).

Note that `rsync` might be a candidate for uninstallation, not because a package depending on it was uninstalled, but because whatever package caused it to be installed no longer depends on it. That is somewhat harder to trace...

As [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381395/how-to-find-which-package-required-another-package/381406?noredirect=1#comment678001_381406) by [cas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas), you can tell `apt` to keep `rsync`, regardless of which package depends on it, by marking it as manually installed, using either `apt-get install rsync` (which won’t actually install `rsync` if it’s already installed), or `apt-mark manual rsync`.

Comment: +1.  one other thing worth mentioning is that if Luc wants rsync to NOT be autoremoved, it's easy to just run `apt-get install rsync` to flag it as manually installed (without actually re-installing it).

Comment: Thanks @cas, I’ve added that to the answer (along with `apt-mark`).

Comment: I didn't know that! That triggers another question: when doing an apt-get upgrade, I sometimes want to withhold some updates while doing other. I've learned that the way to selectively upgrade, is to do `apt-get install <package(s) to upgrade>` and that works. But will that also mark them as manually installed? (I think I should technically open another question for this, but it feels like a really tiny and specific thing to ask.)

Comment: @Luc, you can withhold packages by holding them, using `apt-mark hold` (and `apt-mark unhold` to allow them to be upgraded). I find `aptitude`’s user interface easier to use for this kind of operation; the relevant key there is `:` to hold temporarily, `=` to hold durably (like `apt-mark hold`), `+` to cancel the hold and upgrade (or install). To answer your question, yes, `apt-get install` marks packages as manually installed, even when it upgrades packages.