# Finding recursive and non-recursive depends of a package in Debian

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies, deb

I was reading [How to get ALL kinds of reverse package dependencies: reverse-depends pendant for non-Ubuntu distributions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214138/how-to-get-all-kinds-of-reverse-package-dependencies-reverse-depends-pendant-fo) and tried the same to get info. on couple of packages in Debian but didn't succeed.

```
$ aptitude search aspectj
p   aspectj                                              - aspect-oriented extension for Java - tools                    
p   aspectj-doc                                          - aspect-oriented extension for Java - documentation            
p   libaspectj-java                                      - aspect-oriented extension for Java - library                  
p   libaspectj-java-doc                                  - aspect-oriented extension for Java - API documentation        
p   libaspectj-maven-plugin-java                         - AspectJ compiler Maven Plugin
```

For instance I tried -

```
$ grep-dctrl -FBuild-Depends aspectj  -saspectj /var/lib/apt/lists/*Sources
$
```

As can be seen it didn't give me any output, whereas using

```
$ apt-rdepends aspectj
```

gives me quite a rich list. I do not understand why there is a huge difference between the two commands. Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep-dctrl` command should be

```
grep-dctrl -FBuild-Depends aspectj -sPackage /var/lib/apt/lists/*Sources
```

In the original command given in the answer you’re referring to, you should only replace `mypackage`.